# I can't get a horizontal scroll bar in html front end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the basic html code and css code I used.

```css
.scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 180px !important;
  max-width: 1100px !important;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div class="well">
  <div class="scroll">
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="images/cupertino.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded-active">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="images/saratoga.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="images/sunnyvale.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="images/milpitas.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="images/santa-clara.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="images/san-mateo.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="images/cupertino.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded-active">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me to get an horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: You need to use css to do this, the overflow-x: scroll;

Comment: would you please let us know what you wrote in your class "well" & "scroll"

Comment: Check the "Related" list next to this question... your answer should be in one of the dozen existing css / horizontal scroll bar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use overflow to allow scrollbars.

```css
.well {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.scroll {
  width: 450px;
}
.scroll a {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="well">
  <div class="scroll">
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-60-60-5.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded-active">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-60-60-5.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-60-60-5.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-60-60-5.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-60-60-5.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-60-60-5.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-60-60-5.jpg" alt="..." class="image-rounded-active">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add following css -

```
.scroll { width: 990px; overflow-x: scroll; } /*define the width value to the point from where you want horizontal scroll*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v4vishnuprasad/ddf1uawn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

by css you can achieve this

```
  .scroll{
     overflow-x:scroll;
     height:200px;
     width:400px;
  }
```

by jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".scroll").css({'overflow-x':'scroll','height':'200px','width':'400px'});
    })
```

Comment: I don't think there is any need to put jquery. Alone CSS is enough to do it.

Comment: I am giving you an upvote.

Comment: @Saswat thank you,  i just told both possible ways to do so

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `overflow` property to `auto` or `scroll`.

> scroll
>
> The content is clipped and desktop browsers use scrollbars, whether or not any content is clipped. This avoids any problem with
>   scrollbars appearing and disappearing in a dynamic environment.
>   Printers may print overflowing content.
>
> auto
>
> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers like Firefox provide scrollbars if content overflows.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.well {
  width: 100%;
}
.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.scroll a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.scroll a img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="well">
  <div class="scroll">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="..." class="image-rounded-active">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="..." class="image-rounded">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="..." class="image-rounded-active">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [MDN - overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: ThankYou So much. Your code really helped me and it worked finally which i was stuck for long time.

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below fiddle:

> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpcuxhL1/1/)

```
.scroll {
   width: 300px;
 }
.scroll a {
  float: left;  
}
.well {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```